# Component not rendering when importing

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-cli

I have a a component here in src/components/aboutUs.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>This is a component test</h1>
  </div>
</template>
```

And i have another vue file called Home.vue importing the component aboutUs.

```
  <template>
   <div class="home">
     <div>HELLO !</div>
     <aboutUs/>
   </div>
  </template>

    <script>
    import aboutUs from "@/components/aboutUs.vue";

    export default {
    name: "HomePage",
    components: aboutUs
    };
    </script>
```

But my app.vue only renders "HELLO !" from Home.vue. and not the aboutUs component template. Help please.

Answer (score 3):

You have to wrap your `App` components in `{}`. See [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-registration.html#Local-Registration)

```
components: {
 aboutUs
}
```

Comment: It worked! I wrapped the aboutUs in Home.vue . So this means that, I am also exporting aboutUs to my App.vue right?

Comment: Since `aboutUs.vue` is a child component of `Home` and `Home.vue` is a child component of `App.vue`, then when App is rendered, it also renders About with it since basically it's a grand-child component of App (if that term even exists in the Vue world.)